What is "the manner of the purifying of the Jews" as mentioned in John 2:6?
John 2:6 (KJV):

And there were set there six waterpots of stone, after the manner of the purifying of the Jews, containing two or three firkins apiece.

What is "the manner of the purifying of the Jews"?

The Jews had a tradition of washing their hands before eating.  It was usual for there to be water available for this purpose.  The number and size of the pots indicates there was preparation for many guests.  The text indicates these pots were completely ordinary.

Why do thy disciples transgress the tradition of the elders? for they
wash not their hands when they eat bread. Matthew 15:2


For the Pharisees, and all the Jews, except they wash their hands oft,
eat not, holding the tradition of the elders. Mark 7:3

